# Problem using fetch.pipe() to download image attachments from discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, fetch

I have a discord bot, I'm trying to download an attachment from a slash command but I get this error:

```
TypeError: res.body.pipe is not a function
```

I tried both of these lines with the same error at the pipe:

```
fetch(interaction.options.getAttachment('attachment').url)
    .then(res =>  {
        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(destination);
        res.body.pipe(dest);
    });
```

and

```
fetch(interaction.options.getAttachment('attachment').url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destination));
```

Comment: It seems you expect `.body` to be a [node `Readable` stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable), but if you use `fetch` it's a [web stream](https://nodejs.org/api/webstreams.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're receiving, **TypeError: res.body.pipe is not a function**, typically arises when the response body isn't in the expected readable stream format.

When handling the fetch request in Node.js, the response might not always provide a direct body property that can be piped into a writable stream. To handle file downloading from a URL, you should adjust how you handle the response data.

Here's an approach you could try:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');

// Assuming interaction.options.getAttachment('attachment').url retrieves the attachment URL
const attachmentURL = interaction.options.getAttachment('attachment').url;
const destination = 'path/to/save/your/file.extension'; // Provide the destination path

fetch(attachmentURL)
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to download file: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
        }

        const dest = fs.createWriteStream(destination);

        // Use pipeline to handle streams
        stream.pipeline(res.body, dest, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Pipeline failed:', err);
            } else {
                console.log('File downloaded successfully.');
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error downloading the file:', err);
    });
```

This code uses the `stream.pipeline` method to handle the readable stream `res.body` and pipe it directly to the writable stream (`dest`). It also includes error handling for both the fetch operation and the pipeline process.

Remember to replace `path/to/save/your/file.extension` with the destination where you want to save the downloaded file and ensure proper error handling for the `fetch` operation.

Comment: I get this error: `TypeError: res.body.on is not a function`

here's the res.body btw:
`ReadableStream { locked: false, state: 'readable', supportsBYOB: false }`

also I'm using the native fetch instead of the module, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: In situations where the response body doesn't behave as expected or lacks certain methods like `on`, there could be a need to transform it into a readable stream explicitly. Try using the `stream.pipeline` method to handle the readable stream, which provides a more robust way to pipe streams together. Let me edit the code adapting the new changes.

Comment: Updated the code. Please check and confirm.